# does fscanf make distinction between whitespaces (newline and space)

Tags: c, newline, scanf

I would like to use `fscanf` to process each line of a file that describes a matrix, with one line for each matrix row. I don't know, *a priori*, how many columns or rows the matrix in any given file contains.

It is OK to deal with an unknown number of rows, as it is easy to stop a loop when it reaches the end of file. For example:

```
while(!feof(file)){
    if (fscanf(file, "%f", &f)==1) {
        printf("%f\n",f);
    }
}
```

But I need to know which row the variable `f` belongs to.
For example:

```
n_row = 0;
while(!feof(file)){
    if (fscanf(file, "%f", &f)==1) {
        printf("a value %f is in row %d\n",f,n_row);
        [if you met a "\n"]{
            //then increment the row counter
            n_row++;
        }
    }
}
```

How it is possible to do that?

A.

Comment: `fscanf()` with specifiers `"%c"` `"%[]"` distinguish between newline and space.  Other specifiers not not.  Directives `' '` and `'\n'` do not distinguish either.

Comment: a simple way would be: if ( NULL != strstr( f, "\n" )  Then newline found

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two approaches to doing this:

- Read your input line-by-line with `fscanf`, and then partition it into the individual numbers using either an `sscanf` or `strtok_r` from the line buffer, or
- Try reading one character after the `float`, and check if that character is `\n`.

Here is how the second approach can work:

```
while(!feof(file)) {
    char next;
    int count = fscanf(file, "%f%c", &f, &next);
    if (count > 0) {
        // There may not be '\n' on the last line,
        // in which case count would be equal 1.
        if (count == 1 || next == '\n') {
            //then increment the row counter
            n_row++;
        }
        printf("a value %f is in row %d\n", f, n_row);
    }
}
```

While the second approach corresponds to the solution that you wanted to see, the first approach is more robust.

Comment: Great! In fact, I prefer the second approach as I don't want to store in RAM the whole line. In out code snippet the `printf` line shoud go before the inner `if` loop --I edited the question--.Also, the code works without checking the  `count == 1`.

Comment: @altroware The code will not produce the correct `n_row` after the end of the loop in cases when there is no `'\n'` on the final line. The only reason when it would matter is if your code relies upon `n_row`'s value after the loop is over.

Comment: Good enough code +1, but some minor corner cases.  1) If spaces exists between the last `float` and `'\n'`, the `'\n'` will not be detected.  2) This approach goes into an infinite loop if the scanned input fails to convert to a `float` like with input "XYZ".

Comment: @chux Thanks! That's pretty much the reason why I wrote that the first approach is more robust. Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

There are a number of ways to do this. As dasblinkenlight points out, reading the file using `line-oriented` input and then parsing each line is the most robust way as it allows an unlimited amount of validation to be performed on each element before you add it to the array. Based on this approach, I put together a small example that provides a few additional ways to approach this problem.

You will always have to choose some maximum number of columns to start (you can dynamically allocate each element, but index management become much more challenging). So choose some reasonable number, and then use only the number of columns required. If overall memory use is at a premium, simply reallocate to reduce the column size after you have read the array. There are many, many ways to do this, here is just one example. It will read any number of rows and columns from a filename into an integer array (default max cols is 128 - adjust as necessary). The input file can either be `space` or `comma` separated values.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#define ARRAY_WIDTH 128

int main (int argc, char *argv[]) {

    int *array[ARRAY_WIDTH];    /* create pointer to array of ints of ARRAY_WIDTH   */
    int ridx = 0;               /* row index    */
    int cidx = 0;               /* col index    */
    char *buffer = NULL;        /* getline buffer, NULL forces getline to allocate  */
    size_t len = 0;             /* number of chars for getline to read, 0: no limit */
    ssize_t read;               /* number of characters read by getline             */
    char *ptr = NULL;           /* pointer used to parse buffer & by strtol         */
    char *eptr = NULL;          /* pointer used with strtol                         */
    int tmp = 0;                /* tmp value holding result of strtol conversion    */

    if (argc < 2) {             /* validate sufficient input */
        fprintf (stderr, 
                "Usage:  %s filename [array: space or comma separated values]\n", argv[0]);
        return 1;
    }

    FILE *fp = fopen (argv[1], "r");    /* open input file containing array values  */
    if (!fp) {                          /* validate file open or return             */
        fprintf (stderr, "failed to open file for reading\n");
        return 1;
    }

    while ((read = getline (&buffer, &len, fp)) != -1) { /* read each line in file  */

            array[ridx] = calloc (1, sizeof (array));    /* allocate row            */
            ptr = buffer;

            cidx = 0;           /* reset column index for read of each line         */
            while (*ptr) {      /* parse number of elements in row <= ARRAY_WIDTH   */
                tmp = (int)strtol(ptr, &eptr, 10);      /* convert value to integer */
                if (ptr != eptr) {              /* test that strtol processed chars */
                    ptr = eptr;                 /* set ptr to eptr for next value   */
                    array [ridx][cidx] = tmp;   /* assign value to array            */
                    cidx++;                     /* increase column index            */
                } else {
                    break;
                }
                ptr++;                      /* skip space or comma separator        */
            }
            ridx++;                          /* increase row index                  */
    }

    fclose (fp);                            /* close the file - done reading        */

    /* output values stored in array  - 2 ways          */
    /* fist - use last value of cidx as column index    */
    int i = 0;
    int j = 0;

    printf ("\nProperties of Matrix Read\n\n");
    printf (" size : %d\n rows : %d\n cols : %d\n\n", ridx * cidx, ridx, cidx);

    for (i=0; i < ridx; i++)
    {
        printf (" [");
        for (j = 0; j < cidx; j++)
        {
            printf (" %2d", array[i][j]);
        }
        printf (" ]\n");
    }

    /* second - by using calloc, only assigned values of array are not NULL, this   */
    /* allows iteration over row values without keeping an exact column index       */
    printf ("\nOutput without any column index:\n\n");

    int *p;
    for (i=0; i < ridx; i++)
    {
        printf (" [");
        p = *(array + i);           /* assign pointer to row of array               */
        while (*p)                  /* simply iterate until NULL encountered        */
        {
            printf (" %2d", *p);
            p++;
        }
        printf (" ]\n");
    }
    printf ("\n");

    return 0;
}
```

**input:**

```
$ cat dat/intarray.txt
50 10 21 31 19 22
9 34 32 17 99 91
82 56 78 11 88 2
6 14 24 48 64 3
```

**output:**

```
$ ./bin/a2dyn dat/intarray.txt

Properties of Matrix Read

 size : 24
 rows : 4
 cols : 6

 [ 50 10 21 31 19 22 ]
 [  9 34 32 17 99 91 ]
 [ 82 56 78 11 88  2 ]
 [  6 14 24 48 64  3 ]

Output without any column index:

 [ 50 10 21 31 19 22 ]
 [  9 34 32 17 99 91 ]
 [ 82 56 78 11 88  2 ]
 [  6 14 24 48 64  3 ]
```

Comment: Sounds interesting, but I need to avoid to read the content of a whole line, as it is too big, up to. 2*10^9 columns (!).

Comment: That is what the `len` term is for in `getline` above. You could set it to say `4Meg (2<<32)` and read the line in 4meg chunks until you reach the end. That is part of the flexibility that makes `getline` a good choice.